# How to fix the drag and drop using dev express in c# after fetching data and setting tag property

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, drag-and-drop, devexpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xe6y.png)

```
namespace Implementer
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        #region intit and globals
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView();
            var transactions = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                transactions.Add(new Item { Content = "Item " + i });
            }
            grdTransactions.AllowDrop = true;
            grdTransactions.DataSource = transactions;
            dgmWf.AddingNewItem += (s, e) => transactions.Remove(e.Item.Tag as Item);
        }

        Point mouseDownLocation;
        GridHitInfo gridHitInfo;

        #endregion

        #region events

        public void Mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'vA_ERP4_ADMINDataSet.SYSTEM_MODULES' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //Project initiation
            //Fill drop down for project list
            cmbProject.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(GlobalFunctions.GetConnectionString());
            DataTable dtResult = dataAccess.ExecuteQueryDataSet("select MODULE_CODE, MODULE_DESC from SYSTEM_MODULES where module_is_active=1").Tables[0];

            cmbProject.DisplayMember = "MODULE_DESC";
            cmbProject.ValueMember = "MODULE_CODE";
            cmbProject.DataSource = dtResult;
        }

        private void cmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCurrentProject.Text = cmbProject.Text;

            if (cmbProject.Text != null)
            {
                DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(GlobalFunctions.GetConnectionString());
                DataTable dtTransactions = dataAccess.ExecuteQueryDataSet("select sys_trans_id, sys_trans_desc1 from WF_SYSTEM_TRANS where MODULE_CODE= '" + cmbProject.Text + "'").Tables[0];
                grdTransactions.DataSource = dtTransactions;
            }
        }

        private void btnSalesInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sysTransId = 1001;
            FillTransactionDetails(sysTransId);
        }

        #endregion

        #region drag drop
        private void grdTransactions_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && CanStartDragDrop(e.Location))
            {
                StartDragDrop();
            }
        }

        private void grdTransactions_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            gridHitInfo = grdVTransactions.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
            mouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }

        private void grdTransactions_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridHitInfo != null)
                gridHitInfo.View.ResetCursor();
            gridHitInfo = null;
        }

        private bool CanStartDragDrop(Point location)
        {
            return gridHitInfo.InDataRow && (Math.Abs(location.X - mouseDownLocation.X) > 2 || Math.Abs(location.Y - mouseDownLocation.Y) > 2);
        }

        public void StartDragDrop()
        {
            var draggedRow = gridHitInfo.View.GetRow(gridHitInfo.RowHandle) as Item;
            var tool = new FactoryItemTool(" ", () => " ", diagram => new DiagramShape(BasicShapes.Rectangle) { Content = draggedRow.Content, Tag = draggedRow }, new System.Windows.Size(150, 100), false);
            dgmWf.Commands.Execute(DiagramCommandsBase.StartDragToolCommand, tool, null);
        }

        #endregion

        #region function
        private void FillTransactionDetails(int systemTransactionId)
        {
            //Fill document
            //Fill steps
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(GlobalFunctions.GetConnectionString());
            DataTable transactionDetails = dataAccess.ExecuteQueryDataSet("SELECT DOC_TYPE_DESC1 FROM WF_SYSTEM_TRANS_DT WHERE SYS_TRANS_ID=1001  and MODULE_CODE= '" + cmbProject.Text + "'").Tables[0];
            transactionDetails.Rows.Add();
            grdDocuments.DataSource = transactionDetails;
            grdDocuments.Columns["Details"].DisplayIndex = 2;
            grdDocuments.Columns["Delete"].DisplayIndex = 2;

            DataTable transactionSteps = dataAccess.ExecuteQueryDataSet("select WF_STEP_DESC1 from WF_STEPS where wf_id= 10101  and MODULE_CODE= '" + cmbProject.Text + "'").Tables[0];
            transactionSteps.Rows.Add();
            grdSteps.DataSource = transactionSteps;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't really know where is the mistake and have been looking at it for the past few days and searching for an answer but no luck so I'd be so happy if you could help me out. It was working without the data fetching. but after calling the data it doesn't work. drag it from the grid view and when it reaches the diagram control it would turn into a rectangle with a tag property of it's ID.. With regards to the connection string.. I created a global function to just call it on the main form.